# laravel vue the post method is not supported for this route

Tags: laravel, vue.js, post, routes

I'm trying to implement the importing from CSV.

Below is the /routes/api.php

```
Route::post('caregivers/import', 'CaregiverController@import');

Route::apiResource('caregivers', 'CaregiverController');

Route::post('caregivers/find/consumer_service/{consumer_service}', 'CaregiverController@find');

Route::post('caregivers/assign/consumer_services/{consumer_service}/schedule/{service_schedule}', 'CaregiverController@assign');

Route::post('caregivers/update/consumer_services/{consumer_service}/schedule/{service_schedule}/assignment/{assignment}', 'CaregiverController@updateAssignment');
```

Below is the controller code

```
class CaregiverController extends Controller
{
    .....
    public function import(Request $request)
    {
     .....
    }
}
```

I've called this route using Axios

```
caregiverImport(context, payload) {

            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

                axios

                    .post("caregivers/import", payload, {

                        headers: {

                            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"

                        }

                    })

                    .then(response => {

                        resolve(response);

                    })

                    .catch(error => {

                        reject(error);

                    });

            });

        },
```

It works on local perfectly, but it returns an error when it goes on the server (digital ocean)

Below is the error message

```
The post method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, PUT, PATCH, DELETE.
```

Please help me. What's wrong?